# SQLite in Android: do I have to download any SQLite Administration (like MySQL) or it is already in device memory?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to work with SQLite in Android.
So, do I have to download any SQLite Administration (like MySql) or it is already in device memory?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html, http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ are good tutorials to start with. And you don't need to download any thing like Administrative tool. It will be in device memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is already installed. To inspect the database during development you can use the sqlite3 tool. It is installed in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You Don't need to download anything.its already there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything besides using the built-in tools in the Android SDK. For more information please have a look at the [sqlite documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Basically you can use Java code to create databases, insert records into them, modify them etc.

If you want a graphical way to work on the databases, simply use Eclipse's DDMS View to navigate into your app's databases folder. From there, download the database on your computer and open it with one of the many sqlite applications available.